# Como acessar uma função dentro de um dicionário python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Temos as funções a seguir:

```
def oi():
    print('oi')

def ola():
    print('ola')
```

Agora vamos armazená-las dentro de um dicionário da seguinte forma:

```
saudacoes = {

    'chegada':{
        'simples': oi(),
        'cult': ola(),
    }

}
```

Preciso acessar as funções a depender de dois inputs do usuário, o primeiro diz se é uma saudação de chegada ou de despedida e o segundo qual saudação será, assim:

```
tipo, qual = input().split()
saudacoes[tipo][qual]
```

Vamos supor que o usuário digite:

```
> chegada simples
```

Logo, o programa deveria pesquisar no dicionário da seguinte forma:

```
saudacoes[chegada][simples]
```

E seria de se esperar que ele executasse a função `oi()`. Mas nada acontece. Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você faz `oi()` (com os parênteses) está chamando a função (ou seja, está executando ela) e o retorno dela é colocado como valor do dicionário. Mas como você não colocou nenhum `return` nela, então ela retorna `None`.

Mas as funções são executadas já quando o dicionário é criado, tanto que o código já imprime "oi" e "ola" ao se criar o dicionário.

Se quer guardar a própria função para que ela seja executada depois, tire os parênteses:

```
saudacoes = {
    'chegada':{
        'simples': oi, # sem os parênteses 
        'cult': ola # sem os parênteses 
    }
}
```

E só use os parênteses quando for chamá-la:

```
tipo, qual = input().split()
saudacoes[tipo][qual]()
```

Isso porque `saudacoes[tipo][qual]` refere-se a uma função, e os parênteses servem para fazer a chamada a esta função.